# Printing multiple ints outputs 0

Tags: c, printf

I'm practicing programming in c, but I've come across an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I have a `printf` statement with two markers for two different `int` values. No matter what the first `int` is, it prints 0, but the second `int` prints normally. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a, temp;
int toBinary();
int toDecimal();

int main()
{
    char c;
    for(;;)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        scanf(" %c",&c);
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'a' :
                printf("%d converted to binary: %d\n",a,toBinary());
                break;
            case 'b' :
                printf("%d converted to decimal: %d\n",a,toDecimal());
                break;
            case 'c' :
                printf("EXIT\n");
                return 0;
                break;
            default :
                printf("ERROR c value: %c\n",c);
                return 0;
        } 
    }
}
int toBinary()
{
    if (a == 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        temp = a;
        a /= 2;
        return (temp % 2 + 10 * toBinary());
    }
}
int toDecimal()
{
    int res=0, base = 1, rem;
    while (a > 0)
    {
        rem = a % 10;
        res = res + rem * base;
        a /= 10;
        base *= 2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The problem is that the `printf` statements in the first two cases ignore the actual value of `int a`, but it works normally for the value of the two functions. I'm not sure what's wrong, as `a` is given a value before, in the `scanf` statement, and I am using the proper marker in the text.

Comment: You never check the return value of the first `scanf()`, so perhaps it failed and `a` hasn't gotten a value assigned. That's dangerous.

Comment: @unwind I use the int's value in the functions and they work properly though, or else the second output would be wrong.

Comment: @Comrade_Comski IMO the snippet looks fine, so it is rather the details you assume work OK. Please make your code complete, so everyone could reproduce the issue.

Comment: what @AndriyBerestovskyy meant, we need a [mcve].

Comment: The value is changed in the functions, and I will edit the snippet to include the full code.

Comment: If `a` is modified in the functions, it's undefined behavior, because the order of argument evaluation is unspecified.

Comment: This is a good illustration of why global variables are bad. `toBinary()` and `toDecimal()` should get the value as an argument.

Comment: `temp` should also be a local variable.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that the functions were changing the value of the int, and that's the value that was referenced in the marker. But I don't understand why the `printf` statement wouldn't retrieve the value first, then call the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the order of argument evaluation is unspecified, this is undefined behavior.

The simplest fix would be to save a copy of `a` in a different variable, and print that.

```
int a_copy = a;
printf("%d converted to binary: %d\n",a_copy,toBinary());
```

But it would be better if the function didn't use a global variable in the first place.

```
int toBinary(int a)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        return (a % 2 + 10 * toBinary(a / 2));
    }
}
```

Then you would do:

```
printf("%d converted to binary %d"\n, a, toBinary(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

If `a` is modified in either `toBinary()` or `toDecimal()`, **it's an UB**.

The order of argument evaluation in one function call is unspecified. Some compilers evaluate them L->R (like GCC), some others do it R->L (like VC).

Try this and you'll find it out:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", a, toBinary(), a);
printf("%d %d %d\n", a, toDecimal(), a);
```

Comment: I am using GCC on linux, but I'll be careful to not be vague when handling arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a` in the function `toBinary()` gets reduced to `0` due to presence of the statement `a /= 2;` and it is getting recursively executed.

Hence your printf statement prints `0` for the value of `a`.

As @Barmar suggested, it's a good coding practice to use local variables rather than global variables inside a function.